# best practice to grow python list

Tags: python

I have very large list of list table and I need to add more columns to it.

```
tbl = [range(200),range(200),range(200),...]
newCol = [val1, val2]
```

the way I see it I can do this either:

```
for idx,val in enumerate(tbl)
    tbl[idx] = newCol + val
```

or

```
colRep = [newCol]*len(tbl)
mgr = itertools.izip(colRep,tbl)
newTbl = [ itertools.chain(*elem) for elem in mgr]
```

Is one really better than the other? Is there better way of doing this?

Comment: The former is more readable, IMO, but what do *you* mean by *"better"*? If it's a matter of performance, have you tried any testing/profiling?

Comment: yes, my primary concern is performance. Did not try to test it, I thought may be there is python theoretic answer that will resolve it

Comment: I would go with the former unless the later was much much faster. That said , `colRep = [newCol]*len(tbl)` where `newCol` is a list tends to produce ["interesting" behavior"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Comment: There are other concerns, too - the former operates in-place on the outer list (but creates new inner lists), is that desirable?

Answer (score 2):

For readability, a simple list comprehension would do:

```
In [28]: tbl = [range(2),range(3),range(4)]
In [29]: [newCol + list(elt) for elt in tbl]
Out[29]: 
[['val1', 'val2', 0, 1],
 ['val1', 'val2', 0, 1, 2],
 ['val1', 'val2', 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Note that in Python3, `range` returns a range object, not a list. So to make the code Python2- and Python3-compatible, I changed `newCol + elt` to `newCol + list(elt)`.

If you wish to modify `tbl` *in-place*, you could use

```
tbl[:] = [newCol + list(elt) for elt in tbl]
```

---

Note that before we can compare performance, we need to pin down what is the desired result, lest we end up comparing apples to oranges.

The `for-loop` modifies `tbl` inplace. Is the inplace-ness important?

The `zip/chain` code does not modify `tbl` in-place and instead produces a list
of iterators:

```
In [47]: newTbl
Out[47]: 
[<itertools.chain at 0x7f5aeb0a6750>,
 <itertools.chain at 0x7f5aeb0a6410>,
 <itertools.chain at 0x7f5aeb0a6310>]
```

That could be what you want, but it would be unfair to compare the performance
of these two pieces of code, because the `iterators` delay the process of
enumerating the items inside the iterators. It would be like timing the
difference between painting a house and contemplating painting a house.

To make the comparison more fair, we could use list to consume the iterator:

```
newTbl = [ list(itertools.chain(*elem)) for elem in mgr]
```

---

To benchmark the performance of the various options, you could use `timeit` like this:

```
import timeit
import itertools

tbl = [range(2),range(3),range(4)]
newCol = ['val1', 'val2']

stmt = {
    'for_loop' : '''\
for idx,val in enumerate(tbl):
    tbl[idx] = newCol + val
''',
    'list_comp': '''tbl = [newCol + elt for elt in tbl]''',
    'inplace_list_comp': '''tbl[:] = [newCol + elt for elt in tbl]''',
    'zip_chain': '''
colRep = [newCol]*len(tbl)
mgr = itertools.izip(colRep,tbl)
newTbl = [ list(itertools.chain(*elem)) for elem in mgr]
'''

}
for s in ('for_loop', 'list_comp', 'inplace_list_comp', 'zip_chain'):
    t = timeit.timeit(
        stmt[s], 
        setup='from __main__ import newCol, itertools; tbl = [range(200)]*10**5',
        number=10)
    print('{:20}: {:0.2f}'.format(s, t))
```

yields

```
for_loop            : 1.12
list_comp           : 1.21
inplace_list_comp   : 1.26
zip_chain           : 4.40
```

So the `for_loop` may be marginally faster. Be sure to check this with `tbl`
closer to you actual use case. `timeit` results may differ for a number of
reasons, including hardware, OS, and software versions.

Also be aware that this might be **senseless pre-optimization** if this little
piece of code is not a significant bottleneck in your actual code. For example,
if your actual code spends 1.21 seconds in this list comprehension and 1000
seconds elsewhere, a tenth of a second improvement here would be insignificant
overall.

Comment: i really like this. I only used range as an example; yes, some tables are all integers, yet others are strings.